# Where can I find pre-installed widgets

Tags: linux, debian, kde, plasma

I am trying to find my pre-installed widgets in debian 10 kde plasma, but I cannot find them.
Is there a way to locate their installed path or if anyone know where are they located?

Comment: Have you tried searching the Application Launcher for "widget"? Checked the various System Settings sections? Right click on the "task bar" and try the "configure" or "add widget" options?

Comment: I know how to add, install, remove, uninstall a widget. I am asking about the installation path of those widgets in our system.

Comment: Please edit our question to clarify that. If no one offers an aswer, you might try installing a new widget and then using the `find` tool to find files modified in the last "hour or so".